# Performance Counter Keeping cpuUsage under a certain percentage C#

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

So I'm working on something that checks the CPU Usage under a certain percentage so that it doesn't bog down the system. I have this code:

```
 static PerformanceCounter cpuUsage;

    public static void Main(string[] args)


    {
        cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");


        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
        }

        while (cpuUsage.NextValue() < 50.00);

    }
```

My original thought was to use this do while loop to keep checking the CPU Usage until it went over 50% then stop the loop. But for some reason even if the cpuUsage.NextValue is over 50 it still doesn't exit the loop. I'm  guessing it is some problem with this value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also these are my outputs:                                                           0%
4.6785%
0%
2.34375%
0%
4.6785%
0%
100%
0%
2.345%
                                                                    Any clue why it always returns a 0 in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clue is in the 0% output - the [documentation recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx) you only call NextValue every second so that it has time to get data, but you're actually calling it 3 times every second. Try:

```
float usage;
do {
     Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
     usage = cpuUsage.NextValue();
     Console.WriteLine(usage + " %");
} while (usage < 50.00);
```

Comment: Rob The code worked great. Just had to declare var usage before the loop and just use usage inside of it! thank you so much sir!

Comment: Altered answer so that it compiles, thanks. Glad to have helped.